# How to run a python script on a National Instruments PXI-8840 controller

Tags: python, python-3.x, labview

My goal is to run a python script on a PXI-8840 controller. I found a way to trigger the execution of a python scritp using LabView and the "System Exec.vi". But this will only happen on a Windows Desktop PC which has Python installed.

I think in order to let a Python script with several modules imported run, there must be Python installed on that PXI.

Is there a way to do this? Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have one of these to test them, but according to the manual - you should be able to plug in a USB drive (optical or flash) and install software to your PXI-8840.

[PXI-8840 User Manual](https://www.ni.com/pdf/manuals/374582c.pdf) - on page 13 it references how to install "other software"

I also found this for the next model up running Linux, the PXI-8880. Running Linux you can install new software (including Python interpreter) from their repository.

[PXI-8880 Linux RT controller adding software](https://knowledge.ni.com/KnowledgeArticleDetails?id=kA03q000000x2jQCAQ&l=en-US) - This page also instructs you on how to install the Linux image on your RT controller. (Again YMMV, not sure this is 100% compatible with the 8840)